# $\int \cos^2(x)$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \cos^2(x)\ dx = \int \cos x \cos x \ dx$$

By parts, we have:

$$ \int \cos x \cos x \ dx = \cos x \sin x - \int-\sin x\ \sin x dx = \cos x \sin x + \color{Red}{\int \sin x \ \sin x \ dx}$$

but 
$$\color{Red}{\int \sin x \ \sin x \ dx} = \sin x(-\cos x)-\int\cos x \ (-\cos x) \ dx = -\sin x \ \cos x +\int \cos^2 x \ dx$$

So:

$$\int \cos^2 x \ dx = \cos x \ \sin x-\sin x \ \cos x + \int \cos^2 x dx \implies$$

$$\int \cos^2 x\ dx = 0$$

Where's the error?

Comment: $\int \cos^2 x \ dx = \cos x \ \sin x-\sin x \ \cos x + \int \cos^2 x dx \implies$

$\int \cos^2 x\ dx = \int \cos^2 x\ dx$

^^

Comment: The above two said the error. How to rectify this: substitute $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$ after the first substitution, then simplify.

Comment: @Evariste I didn't get it

Comment: As Evariste is pointing out, your last line doesn't follow from the line above it.

Comment: @user84413  ok, but where's the error? Why can't I find the integral value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts, you have

$\int\cos^2x\,dx=\cos x\sin x+\int\sin^2 x\,dx=\cos x\sin x+\int(1-\cos^2 x)\,dx=\cos x\sin x+x-\int\cos^2 x\,dx$.

Now you can solve this equation for $\int\cos^2 x\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Since comments already explained you the situation, I'll just put here a tip if you want to try a different method of integration:

$$\cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x)$$

Or also

$$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1 + \cos(2x)}{2}$$